# Generate a password unique to an user

Tags: c#, encryption, password-encryption

I want to password protect database file (SQLite). The requirement is to protect DB from being opened by user with external SQL browser, but available in my application.

The idea is to generate an encrypted string that would be unique for each user, but reproducible for the same user.

I tried using ProtectedData class like this:

```
byte[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
byte[] entropy = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 };
byte[] cipher = ProtectedData.Protect(data, entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cipher);
```

Is this a good idea? What other way would be good to accomplish this?

Comment: Hm? Why dont you just protect the file from download? E.g. via .htacess for Apache or via config for IIS?

Comment: @Marcel I don't think he means "browser" in the sense of Internet Browser here, but in the sense of a DB management tool.

Comment: I'd let the user define his own password. If you change the PC, the user name, or whatever, the user might otherwise have problems accessing his database. A good way, however, is to let him enter a password, which is then securely stored in the settings and used every time. Only when you don't see a password in the config, the user needs to enter it again. I'd also implement something to avoid "12345", "pa$$w0rd" and the like...

Comment: If the file should be accessible only to particular users, the standard solution in Windows is to set appropriate access control permissions. If I shouldn't be able to read the database, then don't give me file read permission. On the other hand, if your intent is to give me read access, *but only when running your application*, you're trying to implement a form of DRM, which is inherently broken (but which may pose an effective barrier to users who aren't tech savvy).